# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown current value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

im using twitter bootstrap and using a dropdown menu.

So my dropdown menu has a heading and 3 options.

I want to be able to replace the heading with the value of the option selected

http://jsfiddle.net/jrV6u/30/

i have some jQuery im using but its changing the values of all the dropdown options

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e) 
{ 
    var newHeading = $(this).text();
    $('.dropdown-toggle').html(newHeading);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the direct descendant selector to only change the first `a` element, and also re-append the caret after updating the HTML:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function (e) {
    var newHeading = $(this).text();
    var $heading = $('.dropdown > a');
    var $caret = $('.caret', $heading);
    $heading.html(newHeading + ' ').append($caret);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrV6u/31/)

Comment: This will remove the caret.

Comment: i see what you mean it does remove the caret. i could wrap the text in a separate class and just update that

Answer (score 0):

You should add the classname of the heading to your selector:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(e) 
{ 
    var newHeading = $(this).text();
    $('.dropdown a.dropdown-toggle').html(newHeading);

});
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/jrV6u/27/

Comment: This works fine for just using dummy # links.
But if im actually linking to another page wont it just reload the original heading & overwrite the change applied with jQuery

Comment: scratch that. just going to use jQuery cookie to set it https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js